# cascading dropdown filters with ng-table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ngtable

I'm trying to get filter support on [ngTable](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/) with two external cascading dropdowns. as the documentation shows i have updated filterOptions but seems no luck. please help me

```
$scope.tblInventory = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,
    count: 10,
    filter: $scope.searchObjs,
}, {
    total: 0,
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
        inventoryService.getAllVehicles().then(function (data) {
            params.total(data.length);
            $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        });
    }
});
```

my Html mark up

```
<select class="form-control" id="make" name="make" data-ng-model="searchObj.make"
        data-ng-disabled="!searchObj.makes"
        ng-options="make for make in makes">
    <option style="display:none" value="">Select a make</option>
</select>
<label>
    Model
</label>
<select class="form-control" id="model" name="model" data-ng-model="searchObj.model"
        data-ng-disabled="!searchObj.models"
        ng-options="model for model in models">
    <option style="display:none" value="">Select a model</option>
</select>


<table ng-table="tblInventory" class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in $data">
        <td data-title="'Stock'">
            {{item.stockNumber}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Make'">
            {{item.make}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Model'">
            {{item.model}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually a few issues here. Firstly, you refer to `searchObj` in your view, but the object attached to your scope is actually called `searchObjs`. Secondly, you're not actually using the filter in your `getData` function. So inside your return from `inventoryService`, you need to apply the filter, something like this:

```
      data = params.filter() ?
           $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) :
           data;
      params.total(data.length);
      $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/S2lsTjn4obSz6TmaZV0v) does what you need.

Another thing you might want to consider (though this wouldn't cause your code not to work) is whether you want to call `inventoryService` every time your filter changes. `getData` will be called for every filter change so you might want to retrieve all of the inventory from the service outside `getData`, and only perform your filtering/paging etc inside `getData`.

### Update:

Yes, you can put the call to the service in the main controller function, then add the data and the `ngTableParams` inside the `then` function on the promise return. I've created a new [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PnNDFuast8TS6zkAdKsK) demonstrating this.

Comment: thanks brilliant and thanks you very much for the descriptive answer. yeah i was looking for the way to avoid calling service for each and every filter and paging request do you have any workaround for that jdmcnair??